# Why Django Is Not Accepting Data From A Form Even Data Is Valid? Django-python

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am Working With Modals And Forms In Django I Created A Comment Modal For My Post Modal I Used A ForeignKey To Associate My Comments With Posts, It Works All Fine By Manually  Adding Comments To Posts From Admin Sections Of My Webpage, But As Soon As I Try To Do The Same Thing Using A Front-End Represtantion Of My Form So That User Could Add Comments To Posts, It Doesn't  Work As Expected And I Am Also Unable To Automatically Associate My Posts With My Comments, I Have Been Changing The Things Form 2 Days Now And Still The Result Is Still Same. Can Anyone Help Me :{
This Is How My Modal Look Like:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text =  RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The Form:

```
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Comment
        fields = ['author', 'text']
```

And This My View in Views.py:

```
def article_detail(request, slug):
    article = Article.objects.get(slug = slug)

    articles = Article.objects.all()
    comment_form = CommentForm()



    post = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)

    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =  forms.CreateArticle(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database syet
            new_comment = form.save()
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post =  comment_form.instance.article_id
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'articles/article_detail.html', {'article':article, 'articles':articles, 'comment_form': comment_form , })
```

And The Form Front-End Representation Is As:

```
        <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">

          {{ comment_form }}
          {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: there is no instance in comment_form and you are using `forms.CreateArticle`

Comment: idk what should i change help me plz answers if you leave it's gonna work

Comment: Yes Got It Changed Line  ``` form =  forms.CreateArticle(request.POST, request.FILES) ``` to  ```  form =  forms.CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)```

Comment: are you sure this is the code compiling even?

Comment: yes it doesn't show any error by the way

Comment: Bro Fixed You Help Me Get Out Of The Bug!! I Refreshed The Page An dThe Recent Comment Was There!!! But When I Add The Comment It Gives Attribute Error And Also Adds The Comment To Post When A Come Back And Refresh

Comment: i answered a correct code. Can you watch that?

Comment: I Am Not Downvoting(may be you did it by mistake) But Here  Your Code Has Errors Check It Over, Thanks

Comment: in which line it is showing error

Comment: form =  CommentForm(data=request.POST, filesrequest.FILES) And Also No More Accepting The Comments.  And Also Not Acceptin That Varible At 'post =post'

Comment: edited my answer.

Comment: first error is gone and but still says unexpected argument at  
new_comment = form.save(post=post)

Comment: can you check again?

Comment: Your Are Added To My Teachers List: Guruji

Comment: By They Way How Do I Automaticly  Add Ther Username At Comment Without Asking User type In?  and I am Using User authentication SO I Data We Have The Username But How Do I Put It On Comment

Comment: you can get logged in user from `request.user` and get first_name, last_name from that

Comment: and save the user by attaching with comment like that. `comment. author = '{} {}'.format(request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name)` before the ultimate saving

Comment: Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your correct code should be looked like this

```py
def article_detail(request, slug):

    articles = Article.objects.all()
    comment_form = CommentForm()


    post = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)

    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =  CommentForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database syet
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'articles/article_detail.html', {'article':post, 'articles':articles, 'comment_form': comment_form })
```